# Bouncy Castle Decryption in c# from private key and encrytedtext

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

Encrytped text is:
    wMXLjsRSfO1VngHqotJXoxygP1eTktr3gc3tuhdzXpqOy1N1V8/wflJuHkn1PX7Rf3/ccvL5vzPYYaKIm3s4IMhshrwVH3p4euprwRyNTvlBPLLmZ/b/wuTXkKqRdK81V9oHocIfxerivS4oIJfA4J6fMbtKom6IoE4GVhiAsJs=

My Private Key is:

```
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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 yGNmcNFpgefjm4P4WrH81Ho8ImYp7QH3S35I36CtS1UGsj5OBSSj9ZAIGmkCQDI/
 xowjKMfamLckhg0PLnMJlVvyI8PVelnrIg0NpSTG2VtBsmFFi+Gk2gl/ayp3HEba
 lqPYWEWnjIQVXVnUD8kCQQDJpHSBSFQWRBRGHl2Oyy1SXiBYFdW2FH7+2c1WzN4P
 iKkmgOXqC2RfMD0aE/xtMe8F2zFhPKcARIvEvfneVjmT
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am using Bouncy Castle in c# , when i decrypt using the encrytedtext and private key using below code:

```
keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new RsaEngine();
RsaKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;
cipher.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
byte[] deciphered = cipher.ProcessBlock(bytesl, 0, bytesl.Length);
string decipheredText = utf8enc.GetString(deciphered);
```

I am getting decipheredText as

```
☻♣?????U??`?u????|???^H?|???☺????♦M>?→?&↔.0p?J??a?▼?S←$*▬T☼?  xQ??-??Ai9;??siqD??_???  ♥↓§?k?Ny??kr?U??↔z Mazher Ul Haq
```

but my actual string was "Mazher Ul Haq" , How to get actual string

Comment: This almost looks like a padding issue.  You are decrypting your string, but you are getting a lot of extra bytes on the front end of it.  Take a look at the accepted answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128261/c-sharp-rsa-decryption-using-bouncy-castle) for a C# example of decrypting base 64 formatted encrypted text.

Comment: @gtrig thanks for your comment my problem got solved from the link you provided IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

Comment: Don't you need the _public_ key to decrypt content? Normally the private key is only used for encrypting.

Answer (score 2):

Your "encrypted text" is actually base64 text. I suspect that if you convert that into non-base64 data first, you should be fine. If you've already got it as a string, that's as simple as:

```
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);
```

If you need to convert it to a string first:

```
string base64Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64Binary);
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);
```

Comment: can u explain me more specifically, i am getting an error while converting to non-base64, assuming tat encryted text is like  string base64 ="that encrypted  text here";

Comment: @MazherUlHaq: "I am getting an error" gives us very little information. There's no way I can help you with so little to go on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it dint help, i solved problem using by adding padding IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());