# RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING encryption algorithm for windows phone 8.1 universal app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, rsa

What is RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING algorithm?
And I need to encrypt a string data using public key by RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING in windows phone 8.1 .
How can i do that ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

After digging and searching on many sources. I found the solution from stack over flow itself.
For that I used WinRT Ported version of Bouncy Castle.

[C# RSA Decryption using Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128261/c-sharp-rsa-decryption-using-bouncy-castle)

And I encrypted data successfully.

Comment: The supposed duplicates is about using Bouncy Castle, whereas this question is open to other approaches, such as the crypto built into WP8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core` namespace.

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider=AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
```

You can use this object to implement the algorithm. The example in below link can help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.aspx

Comment: so how to encrypt data ?

Comment: You need to use the `CryptographicEngine` class. After using the `AsymmetricAlgorithmProvider` to create a `CryptographicKey` object, use the `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods of `CryptographicEngine` class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.encrypt.aspx